# ActionScript 3 MovieClip class linkage

Tags: actionscript-3, class, movieclip, linkage

I'm simply playing around with basic ActionScript 3 using Flash CS3 Pro.

I put in a keyframe this very simple code to duplicate n "brander" symbols:

```
for (var i:Number=0; i<20; i++) {
    var m = new brander("MS_"+i);
    addChild(m);
    m.name = "MS_"+i;
    m.x = 20*i;
    m.alpha = a;
    a-=0.05;
    m.y = 20;
}
```

The symbol is linked to brander.as class.

The class is this one:

```
package {
    import flash.display.*;
    public class brander extends MovieClip {
        var n:String;
        //
        public function brander(name) {
            setName(name);
        }
        //
        function setName(name) {
            this.n = name;
        }
        //
        function getName() {
            return n;
        }
    }
}
```

and it is simple too.

Now: I noticed I can't really set anything in this class. So, when I call setName (at the creation of a "brander" instance), I don't set anything. Is this possible?

I tested without debugging, by simply writing:

```
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, test);
//
function test(EVT) {
    trace(this.getChildByName("MS_2").getName());
}
```

Why do we link a class when this class can't store information? What am I doing wrong?

---

EDIT:

I found this is working:

```
function fun(EVT) {
    trace((this.getChildByName("M_2") as brander).getName());
}
```

but I can't understand WHY: could you please tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the getChildByName() funcction returns a DisplayObject. The DisplayObject has no getName function. The brander class however inherits from (extends) the DisplayObject, and therefore you can store it as a DisplayObject. But if you want to call any of the brander functions, you need to cast it to brander first, using as.

There is lots of information on [casting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cast_%28computer_science%29), [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) and [inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28computer_science%29) several places on the internet.

Comment: I know what casting, etc. actually are in terms of OOP. As a seasoned AS1 and AS2 developer (slowly and lazily moving to AS3) I thought it was some Flash authoring issue, not a programming-related one. Thanks you for taking the time to reply.